# Certbot on ubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, certificate, nginx

I'm new to running my own server so go easy on me please!

I think I messed up - went through the digital ocean droplet set up and didn't select the LTS version of ubuntu, so I'm on 22.10. Left certs to the end and discover that certbot doesn't support 22.10, or at least doesn't mention it.

Does it matter that much?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually software will run without problems on a distribution slightly newer than what its instructions suggest. (Most problems occur when the distribution provides components that are *too old*, less so when they're too new.)

In this case, Ubuntu itself provides certbot [packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=certbot) via 'apt' for both 22.04 and 22.10; it's the packager's responsibility to do any necessary changes for the packaged software to work. So even if "upstream" certbot were to have some incompatibilities out of the box, the Ubuntu-provided packages would have those fixed somehow.

The instructions found in Certbot's website for Ubuntu actually tell you to use *Snap* packages instead of 'apt' packages. Snap, very much like Docker, isolates the program from the OS and requires it to bring its own libraries and runtimes independent from what the host OS normally has – the same latest Certbot version in a Snap container can run equally well on both Ubuntu 16.04 and 22.04.

Finally, Certbot doesn't issue certificates on its own – it's just a client for various ACME-compatible certificate authorities – so it could be completely replaced with [another ACME client](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=certbot), such as LEGO or Step. Some web servers even have ACME support built in (like mod_md in Apache httpd) and wouldn't need any external client at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, appreciate it! I eventually decided to install an earlier version and take the pain now rather than upgrading every 6 months or so until next year. Not sure if this was the right approach, but setting everything up again reinforces my learning anyway! Thanks again :)